# Will allow payment using paypal for download epub ios

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, epub

i am developing a ePub reader and to download that epub from website, using paypal integration.

is apple allows to download non-apple product ??

and if no what should i use to buy from my app ?

thanks...

Comment: I think this might not be acceptable.  You are not allowed to use an integrated payment system to purchase digital goods unless it is Apple's IAP framework.  I think they will instruct you to redirect the user to a webpage in this case.

Comment: ok so i have to use in-app purchase rite ?

Comment: That is my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is an 3rd party api..

Use Braintree. you can surf [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com) for more infomation

Infact I am also using it..:)

[image]

Comment: Thanks .... for quick reply but i am downloading epub books and as i know for Digital books i can use in app Purchase, am i correct ?

Comment: may be.. u can go through the link i Have provided you.. mine is Shopping app where i am using payment method by paypal. so try to R&D about it. Sure You will get a solution..:) I am attaching a screenShot  u can check it. and what I think inApp purchase can also use this SDK

Comment: Is it support currency in GEL , is it possible ?

Comment: YES.. it support many currencies.. you can clear your more queries from [here this link](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/node/reference/currencies)